# how to sort a dictionary val along with the key in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have two dictionary, and I need to sort one of the dictionary along with key and value. As sorting is not provided for dictionary, how can i achieve this?
considering a dictionary which i wan to sort will be:

```
list1 = [10.0035,12.3243,0.7654,15.2487,2.1222, 7.8768]
list2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
dic = {'val': list1, 'key': list2}
```

So, when i sort it, it should display like :

```
>>> dic 
{'key': [2,4,5,0,1,3], 'val':[0.7654,2.1222, 7.8768,10.0035,12.3243,15.2487]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can still sort the lists; it doesn't matter that they are stored in a dictionary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip the values together, sort, and unzip:

```
dic['val'], dic['key'] = zip(*sorted(zip(dic['val'], dic['key'])))
```

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [10.0035,12.3243,0.7654,15.2487,2.1222, 7.8768]
>>> list2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> dic = {'val': list1, 'key': list2}
>>> dic['val'], dic['key'] = zip(*sorted(zip(dic['val'], dic['key'])))
>>> dic
{'key': (2, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3), 'val': (0.7654, 2.1222, 7.8768, 10.0035, 12.3243, 15.2487)}
```

The fact that the two lists happen to be values in a dictionary doesn't prevent them from being sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort them before even creating the `dict` and then create the dict

```
list1, list2 = [10.0035,12.3243,0.7654,15.2487,2.1222, 7.8768], [0,1,2,3,4,5]
key, val = zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2)))
print dict(key=key, val=val)
# {'val': (2,4,5,0,1,3), 'key': (0.7654,2.1222,7.8768,10.0035,12.3243,15.2487)}
```

Comment: @varsha_holla Happy to have been of help :)